# Is an object allowed to legally change its type during its lifetime in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, polymorphism, rtti, virtual-functions

I have this code:

```
class Class {
public:
    virtual void first() {};
    virtual void second() {};
};

Class* object = new Class();
object->first();
object->second();
delete object;
```

that I compile with Visual C++ 10 with /O2 and have this disassembly:

```
282:    Class* object = new Class();
00403953  push        4  
00403955  call        dword ptr [__imp_operator new (4050BCh)]  
0040395B  add         esp,4  
0040395E  test        eax,eax  
00403960  je          wmain+1Ch (40396Ch)  
00403962  mov         dword ptr [eax],offset Class::`vftable' (4056A4h)  
00403968  mov         esi,eax  
0040396A  jmp         wmain+1Eh (40396Eh)  
0040396C  xor         esi,esi  
283:    object->first();
0040396E  mov         eax,dword ptr [esi]  
00403970  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
00403972  mov         ecx,esi  
00403974  call        edx  
284:    object->second();
00403976  mov         eax,dword ptr [esi]  
00403978  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
0040397B  mov         ecx,esi  
0040397D  call        edx  
285:    delete object;
0040397F  push        esi  
00403980  call        dword ptr [__imp_operator delete (405138h)]
```

Note that at `00403968` the address of the object start (where `vptr` is stored) is copied into `esi` register. Then at `0040396E` this address is used to retrieve the `vptr` and the `vptr` value is used to retrieve address of `first()`. Then at `00403976` the `vptr` is retrieved again and is used to retrieve the address of `second()`.

Why is vptr retrieved twice? Could the object possible have its `vptr` changed in between calls or is it just an underoptimization?

Comment: Weird. I thought it should all be a no-op. It's probably an underoptimization, if it looked inside the functions it could have seen that neither of them change `esi`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is vptr retrieved twice? Could the object possible have its vptr changed in between calls or is it just an underoptimization?

Consider:

```
object->first();
```

This call may destroy the object and create a new one in the same chunk of memory. Hence, after this call no assumptions can be made about the state. E.g.:

```
#include <new>

struct Class {
    virtual void first();
    virtual void second() {}
    virtual ~Class() {}
};

struct OtherClass : Class {
    void first() {}
    void second() {}
};

void Class::first() {
    void* p = this;
    static_assert(sizeof(Class) == sizeof(OtherClass), "Oops");
    this->~Class();
    new (p) OtherClass;
}

int main() {
    Class* object = new Class();
    object->first();
    object->second();
    delete object;
}
```

Compilers may optimize away unnecessary register loads if that function is inline and/or link-time code generation is used.

---

As DeadMG and Steve Jessop noted the above code exhibits undefined behaviour. According to 3.8/7 of C++ 2003 Standard:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied, and
> - the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> - the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and
> - the original object was a most derived object (1.8) of type T and the new object is a most derived object of type T (that is, they are not base class subobjects).

The above code doesn't satisfy requirement 2 from the above list.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Maybe LTCG doesn't help *yet*, but it's an optimisation that's available to potential future compilers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: gcc-4.7.1 optimizes the original code as posted into a call to  `operator new()` followed by a call to `operator delete()` with `-O3`. Do you care to provide any supporting evidence for you claim?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin you used gcc with visual C++? Because otherwise, you're not answering the question. This is about a specific compiler with a specific setting (-O2). And with visual C++, -O2 with link-time code generation yields the same result.

Comment: Not really. Creating anything except another `Class` in that space would be a giant pile of UB. The compiler does not have to concern itself with this potential scenario.

Comment: @DeadMG: _Creating anything except another Class in that space would be a giant pile of UB._ Well, not really. Do you care to provide any supporting evidence to this bold claim?

Comment: @Maxim: `object->second()` is UB. The pointer `object` does not validly refer to any object, certainly not the newly-created object of type `OtherClass`. See 3.8/7 in the standard. Your code violates the second bullet point ("the new object is of the same time as the original object") or the fourth ("they are not base class sub-objects"), depending whether it's the complete object or its `Class` base that you think `object` refers to. In fact it refers to neither, although in practice of course it still contains the same address. So you won't see a problem unless optimization screws you.

Comment: @SteveJessop: _The pointer object does not validly refer to any object, certainly not the newly-created object of type `OtherClass`._ I don't see why it wouldn't validly refer to an object. After the call to `object->first()` `object` pointer validly refers to the newly created `OtherClass` object, does it not?

Comment: @Maxim: no, it does not. 3.8/7 specifically states that it refers to the new object if the conditions are met. The conditions are not met. There's nothing else anywhere in the standard to say that it refers to the new object (if there was something, then what would be the point of 3.8/7 carefully defining those conditions, when the pointer refers to the new object whether they're met or not?). So it doesn't refer to the new object. It used to refer to the old object, but you destroyed the old object.

Comment: That is, as far as the standard is concerned. It's possible that MSVC has taken it upon itself, as an extension, to allow the pointer to refer to the new object, and that's why `vptr` is re-loaded. But there are other reasons `vptr` might have been re-loaded, so we can't conclude from this code that MS guarantees that will always happen.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I've taken a look at 3.8/7 and it does indeed require the new object to be of exactly the same type for the pointer to remain valid. That's a bit surprising that it doesn't allow for a derived class of the same size. May be it is to allow a compiler to avoid reloading the vtable pointer after each virtual call (an optimization MSVC doesn't do here).

Answer (score 2):

It is stored in `esi` to be saved between the calls to different functions.

The Microsoft convention says

> The compiler generates prolog and epilog code to save and restore the ESI, EDI, EBX, and EBP registers, if they are used in the function.

so the pointer stored in `esi` will remain, but the `this` pointer in `ecx` might not.

Comment: Okay, the start of object is stored in `esi`, but why is `vptr` read twice?

Comment: Also keeping the `vptr` would require an additional register, like `edi`, which would then have to be saved and restored. Would that improve the code? Hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question from the title first:

Yes, an object from a derived class changes its type during construction and destruction. This is the only case.

The code in the body of the question is different. But as Maxim correctly notes, you just have a pointer. This pointer may point (at different times) to two different objects residing at the same address.